# Cookies not included in GET call from Angular to different server?

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies, single-sign-on, cross-domain

We have an angular website, let's call it `https://webui.foo.com`.  We are moving our infrastructure to SOA (Service-oriented architecture) so we have offloaded a lot of our business-specific functionalities to web api-based endpoints on various servers.

Recently, we built out SAML2 support for SSO (Single Sign-On) from our authentication server (authsvc.foo.com).  The standard flow is, webui has a link for clients that redirects them to something like `https://authsvc.foo.com/sso/saml2?idp=some-idp&redirectUrl=https://webui.foo.com/sso-response`.

The authentication service, upon getting a request on that endpoint, will look up the third-party IDP (Identity Provider), load its metadata, and redirect the challenge to the IDP.  The IDP will then properly authenticate the user and return to the authentication service an assertion that we can use to validate and identify the user.  Once this happens, the authentication service sets a short-lived encrypted cookie called `SSOToken` only available for `https://authsvc.foo.com/api/auth/sso` and sends a redirect to the specified `redirectUrl` in the original URL sent by the webui.

What's supposed to happen next, is the `/sso-response` endpoint (an angular endpont) is supposed to immediately perform an http GET operation to `https://authsvc.foo.com/api/auth/sso` with the `SSOToken` cookie, and when the authsvc sees that cookie and validates it, will respond with a valid JWT and refresh token for use in our web application.

We can test the components of the authentication service by using a URL like `https://authsvc.foo.com/sso/saml2?idp=some-idp&redirectUrl=https://authsvc.foo.com/api/auth/sso`, which shows us on the browser (after authentication through SAML) the expected JWT and refresh token... so this part seems to be working correctly.

However... when we GET `https://authsvc.foo.com/api/auth/sso` from the `\sso-response` angular endpoint, we get a 401.  Looking into the request, we see the `SSOToken` cookie is simply not included in the request... which seems odd, since it seems like it should be set from the browser automatically, yet it clearly is not doing so.

We've read a bit about using `withCredentials` but that doesn't seem to make any difference.  There's also some discussion about CORS, but we aren't getting any CORS errors or warnings... we're just not getting the cookie attached to the request, even though the browser certainly knows about the cookie.

What is going on here?  What are we doing wrong?  I apologize, I'm not an angular guy (I built the SAML support on the authentication server) so my understanding of what needs to happen (or not happen) on the front-end to make this work eludes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO IT TURNS OUT that the culprit was the `SameSite` Cookie property.  I had set it to "Lax", thinking this would allow for the cross-site communication to work... but no.  Apparently modern browsers frown on that without ensuring a "Secure" property on the cookie.  Who knew?  I guess it makes sense, but this isn't really something I need to worry about cross-site security issues already, so it was not in my consideration.

What I ended up doing is changing the Cookie properties to `SameSite=None; Secure` and the cookie was transmitted with the request.  I expect I could have still used the `Lax` setting with the `Secure` setting, but I found something that works so I'll keep with it.

Answer (score 0):

How is the cookie set, with which options and configurations ?

Cookies have a "Domain" part which tells the browser where it belongs to.
If you want it to be sent to be available to all subdomains, like `webui.foo.com` and `authsvc.foo.com`, you'll need to set the cookie with a dot before the the domain like so `.foo.com`.

Your angular endpoint `\sso-response` might not know that there is a cookie that needs to be attached to the request.

See how youtube sets the cookie domain:
[image]

Comment: The values are pretty targeted: Domain=authsvc.foo.com, Path=/api/auth/sso, SameSite=Lax